# How to find out local and remote time difference?

Tags: windows, unix, ntp

I face strange situation: I suspect some of Windows PCs in the network are suddenly become out-of-sync with our NTP servers. So I need something I can remotely check time difference between Windows machine and NTP server. What can be the best is to log that difference so I will be able to graph it and see the moment it happens to debug further.

And, of course, I'd prefer remote tool that I'll run on some extra PC so I won't install anything on each of client PCs around network.

I also find out that some of clients are happy to sync with unix-based NTP server and won't sync with Windows-based (DC), while some other 'like' Windows-based NTP server. Something strange, indeed, but the network is legacy and I can suspect pretty everything.

Comment: not a programming question. Voting to move to serverfault.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin runs nicely on Windows, and you can use "ntpdate -q" to find the date on the remote server and "date" to get the machine on the local server. A short shell script later and you should be done -- you can then automatically capture the time difference.

Comment: This is something I'd better live without - deploy these components (ntpdate + script + whatever interpreter I like) on every (ok, on every suspected) Windows machine. May there be any way to remotely check time on Windows machine from one central (let's call it 'timecheck') server?

Comment: There might be. I have no idea if Windows boxes respond to ntp in their default install. Why not run ntpdc against one and check? If they do, you can query the time on the remote machine using ntp tools.